# Private messaging option

Tags: feature-request

Not exactly sure where my question went from last night, but I would like some way to privately talk to someone so that if and when problems arise, they can be dealt with in a private matter.  Not out in the open to air out dirty laundry.

Answer (score 7):

The official Stack Exchange policy on this feature request is a pretty firm No. There's extensive discussion on [meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) if you'd like to read some more about the reasoning. I'm not sure I 100% agree with this position, but there it is.

The best option available is chat. It's certainly a good place to catch a mod if you want to talk to us about something.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I wish that it be made known to Aaronut that I do not want him to comment on any of my questions.  I do not feel that he is a positive influnce for me personally, and I do not like him.  ANY time I have had contact with him it always ends up in me getting frustrated.  I am so close to leaving because of him, and I rather enjoyed this site until I came across him.

Comment: I had wanted to do this in a private setting instead of airing it out in a chat room, hence the reason I asked the question.

Comment: If you feel that is the best way to go about it, then I shall say it in chat.

Comment: Well, it's not necessarily a great option, but it's the only option, and that comes down from the dev team, so there's nothing we can do about it.

Comment: While not a great option, it is the only one that I am allowed to do.  But maybe you can relay the message to him as well.  I do not want any contact from this person from here on out.

Comment: I am sure that if you stick within the site guidelines, the mods will leave you alone. If you have an issue with a particular question, you should ask about it here on Meta. I didn't see what went down, and the comments are gone now, but in general, if your posts need moderator attention, they're going to get it. Whether it's me or someone else, and asking that a particular mod not have any contact with you is unrealistic and is not going to happen. However, we are human, so if you think we're wrong, please bring it up on meta.

Comment: You wouldn't be the only person that has disagreed with us and we try and handle everyone fairly.

Comment: Even asking questions and him answering is not a pleasant experience.  I just want him to leave me alone.  You are human, and that is why I am asking him to leave me alone.  I am trying to not let him run me off of this site.  He does not make me feel like I am welcomed here.  I am not going to try to separate my culinary point of view when they are so deeply connected and rooted in each other.  I have a duty to try to protect people, and when I feel that my duty is being jeopardized by someone, I am sticking up for myself.

Comment: My passions in life are cooking and nursing and they go HAND IN HAND.  I change lives every day at work, and when I am able to integrate that with my passion for cooking, it justifys why I am doing what I am doing with my life.  And then saying my research is pseudoscience when I have looked up things in nursing journals.  I also have a background in biology and a minor in chemistry, so I am a scientist by nature.  Needless to say, that he has offended me and I wish to not have any contact with him.

Comment: What I want to do is if I ever decide to post a question on here is to put in the comment section and ask him to not post a response because I will not read it nor accept it.  But I don't like the idea of having to do that on every post, which is why I wanted to see if a private messaging option could be added.

Comment: That's fine, but it's worth noting that health and nutrition are explicitly off topic here. From the [FAQ] "The following are considered off topic here: General health and diet issue (e.g. "Is cauliflower healthy?")" There was extensive discussion of this when the site started. The consensus was that it's a new field with a lot of pseudo-science and plenty of nut jobs (I'm not implying that you are either of those). As such, the community (not just 3 mods) elected to make it off topic as a whole. Agree or disagree, that's the sites policy, and it's one we'll enforce.

Comment: @AtlasRN let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1220/discussion-between-yossarian-and-atlasrn)